# GeoDjango: editing the standard PostGIS template to include OSGB36

Tags: postgresql, geodjango

I've just installed GeoDjango (yay) and now I'm trying to follow [these instructions](http://github.com/mysociety/mapit/blob/master/README) to set up an existing GeoDjango project, which needs OSGB36:

```
After you've installed and got a PostGIS template, log
in to it and update the proj4text column of SRID 27700 to include
+datum=OSGB36, and update SRID 29902 to have +datum=ire65.
```

However. If I connect to [the postgis_template created as part of the GeoDjango install](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatialdb-template), it doesn't appear to have any rows or columns at all:

```
domesday=# \c template_postgis
psql (8.4.4)
You are now connected to database "template_postgis".
template_postgis=# \d
No relations found.
```

How do I make the edits necessary to update SRID 27700 and SRID 29902 as described here? Have I created template_postgis wrong? I didn't see any errors during install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should see is:

```
template_postgis=# \d
              List of relations
 Schema |       Name       | Type  |  Owner   
--------+------------------+-------+----------
 public | geometry_columns | table | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys  | table | postgres
(2 rows)
```

Since you're not, you probably had a problem running:

```
$ psql -d template_postgis -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/postgis.sql
```

On my (Ubuntu+PG8.3) system, that file is actually called lwpostgis.sql. I had similar issues when installing the first time.